# HttpServletResponse.setHeader Content-Type Not As Entered

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jetty, jetty-9

Don't know in which combinations java/spring-boot/servlet-api version, but it was possible to set

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "plain/text; charset=utf-8");
```

Note the space before charset.

In current versions, it seems that setHeader is doing some transformation and removes the space, so I end up with "plain/text;charset=utf-8".

```
System.out.println("***000");

response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

System.out.println("000=" + response.getHeader("Content-Type") + "=000");
```

Returns:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ***000
[INFO] GCLOUD: 000=text/plain;charset=utf-8=000
```

Before:

```
cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:21
content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
date:Thu, 26 Oct 2017 20:26:04 GMT
expires:0
pragma:no-cache
server:Google Frontend
status:200
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:DENY
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

After:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Application-Context: application
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Server: Development/1.0
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2017 20:22:39 GMT
Content-Length: 1
```

Is there any way to modify this header before sending it back to the client. I have an old client depending on that.

A solution with servlets would be fine as well.

Is there a way to write raw data to a client in spring framework?

Comment: The difference between before and after is the jetty version 6 vs 9. Need to understand now if it's possibility to override this behaviour?